# Checkbox checked after form submit in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I code in smarty,In My Form there are many Checkboxes,When I check it then submit it Properly in DB,But I want that: When I open the Form next then "It should be remain check" As Checked Earlier.But My Form is not Working like this feature. I have .tpl file.My Code is Below:

```
    <div class="header_text">Brand</div>
    <table style="margin-left: 94px;">

    {foreach from=$interests item=record}
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 150px;">
                <div class="interest_name">
                    <div class="interest_name">

                    {$record.name}
                    </div>

                </div>
            </td>
               {foreach from=$record.type item=type}
                <td style="width: 150px;">


            {* I want to check checkbox after form submit based on Previously selected Form Submission*}      
            <input type="checkbox" name="plan_type[{$record.id}][]" value="{$type}" />
            {$type}



                    <div id="comments">
                        <textarea name="comments[{$record.id}][]" cols="7" rows="2" value="comment"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </td>

                {/foreach}
            <td style="...">
                <input type="checkbox" name="shop" value="Shop" />Shop
                <textarea name="comments[{$record.id}][]" cols="7" rows="2" value="comment"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {/foreach}
       </tr>


       <div class="shaukk-buttons universal-red-button home-page-buttons">
        <a herf="#">Add Details</a>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="enter" name="submit">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to pass the value through php:

```
global $smarty;

if(isset($_POST["checkboxname"])){
    $smarty->assign("checkboxvalue", $_POST["checkboxname"]);
}
```

Then in your template:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname" value="{$type}" {if !empty($checkboxvalue) && $checkboxvalue == $type}checked="checked"{/if}/>
```

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to accept an answer if it solved your issue, so your question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure of what you want, but you can check an input just using a condition inside the code and sending to smarty the appropiate value in order to trigger the condition, ie:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="plan_type[{$record.id}][]" value="{$type}" {if $recordcheck}checked="checked"{/if}/>
```

Comment: smarty cannot know by itself what you want unless you pass a variable, so you'll have to use php to decide if the checkbox has to be checked or not and pass a boolean variable. ie $smarty->assign('recordcheck', true);